# print css: printing cut-off at the bottom of page on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am having real trouble trying to get printing to work:

https://www.sunnysideup.co.nz/test-page

I have tried tons of different combinations of padding and margin for HTML / BODY / PAGE in the css, but without any success.

It takes a bit of checking, but you can see some of the lines are cut off at the bottom. You can see that page 2 and 3 are cut off. Feel free to explore other pages on the site too, you will see that pages in print are regularly cut-off at the bottom.

Here is the simplified print scss if that helps:

```
@page {
    // width: 210mm;
    // height: 297mm;
    margin-top: 20mm!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    overflow: visible!important;
    margin-bottom: auto!important;
    // padding-bottom: 4rem!important;
}
@page:first {
    margin-top: 0mm!important;
}
@media print {
    body,
    html {
        overflow: visible!important;
        margin-bottom: auto!important;
        font-size: 10px!important;
        *, *:before {
            color: $colour_black_rock_n_roll!important;
        }

        #main {
            margin-bottom: auto!important;
            overflow: visible!important;
            padding: 1rem 12rem 0 12rem!important;
            * {
                overflow: visible!important;
            }
            &:before {
                display: block;
                background-image: url(./images/SSU_Logo_horizontal_.png)!important;
                background-position: top left;
                background-size: contain;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                page-break-before: auto;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: avoid;
                &:before, &:after {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Plz mention the page/line/section on the print. There are 5 page.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal thank you for feedback. Almost every page is cut off. I have added some details about this.

Answer (score 3):

```css
@media print {
    .element-you-donnot-want-to-be-cut-off {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin-bottom` on `@page`:

```
@page {
      margin-bottom: 30mm !important;
}
```

See it in action on Codepen: https://cdpn.io/manaskhandelwal1/debug/QWGNqrP/PBMNWRNoyoJr

Comment: Awesome - but can you explain me why this would work - i.e. I am worried that it may accidentally work, but not work on other pages. Also, does it matter if you use mm or rem or another measurement? I.e. I am wondering why 30mm exactly. I tried, for example: margin-bottom: 10rem and that definitely did not work.

Comment: @NicolaasThiemenFrancken I used `mm` because you were using it. You can use any unit. At first, try giving a very high-value ex `20rem` or `200px` etc so that you can see a significant change. I have tested both `px` and `rem` and they are working.

Comment: @NicolaasThiemenFrancken And about `30`. I just got it by hit and trial. Try different values and then uses the one which you found the best.

Comment: I guess what I am after is to take out the guessing. It may work for 30mm in one instance, but I want it to work with 30mm because I understand why.

Comment: @NicolaasThiemenFrancken `mm` and `cm` should only be used for printing works and for other works use `rem, em, px`.